# Subscribe multiple FormControl(s) only once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have filtered out few FormControl(s) from a large FormGroup based on some logic now - I'd like to know how can I merge / combine those selected FormControls and have only one subscribe..

I looked into RxJS docs and marble diagrams but didn't understand it properly. It's very confusing to understand all of these and know which one to use for my case:

```
- forkJoin
- combineLatest
- merge
- join
- zip
```

Here's more detailed info about the question:

Let's say 2 FormControls (i.e., controlA, controlB). I want to execute my some `handlerFunction` whenever any of the FormControl value changes.
* It needs to execute my handlerFunction once whenever any control valueChanges (In my case any one control will be changed at one time)

Thanks.

Comment: when an event fires, do you want the know the values of both inputs or only of the one that changed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The best option for you is `combineLatest` that emits after all source Observables emitted at least one value and then on every emission from any source Observable:

```
Observable.combineLatest(controlA.valueChanges, controlB.valueChanges)
  .subscribe(...);
```

Eventually you can chain each source with `startWith(null)` to guarantee that every source will emit one item immediately and filter what you want in the subscriber.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    controlA.valueChanges.startWith(null),
    controlB.valueChanges.startWith(null)
  )
  .subscribe(([val1, val2]) => ...);
```

Btw, about the other operators:

- `zip` - emits only when all sources emitted the same number of items
- `forkJoin` - emits when all sources emitted at least one item and completed (never happens with `valueChanges`)
- `merge` - just merges Observables but you can't know which one emitted what value
- `join` - I don't think that's part RxJS 5

Comment: Thanks for answer, this helps very much and a good and easy description to all other functions and it's usage.
FYI: In my case I don't need `.startWith(null)` as per my situation logic.
Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Thanks mate, I was trying to combine an Observable stream of Episodes coming from my Store select AND a search value. I used combineLatest but then didn't have an initial search value on page load. So `startWith` came to the rescue. One note, you know have to use a pipe: `this.searchValue.valueChanges.pipe( startWith( '' ) )`

Comment: wonder why forkJoin doesnt work with valueChanges on form control

Comment: @KhuramNiaz `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to emit at least one item and complete. `valueChanges` is a Subject that never completes because that would mean it will never emit any more items.

Answer (score 9):

For those getting combineLatest as deprecated, try combining the valueChanges observables in an array. Also, for those getting startWith as deprecated, try not using null.

```
combineLatest([
    this.typeSelected.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
    this.checkedFC.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(false))
  ]
).subscribe(([type, checked]) => {
   console.log([type, checked]);
});
```