# How can I pipe two data streams/observables in the same pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular8

I have two forms in one view, each outputting changes. I have a global directive with two selectors to get both streams.

I can easily handle one form but when I have two, and place each in its own pipe or directive, they mess up each others save function, so to speak, so I need both in the same pipe. (Or another solution ;)

**Form component**

```
<form name="shop_info"
      autocomplete="off"
      #f1="ngForm"
      (SubmitShop)="save($event)"
      [SaveShop]="f1"
      *ngIf="merchant">
...
</form>
...
<form name="region"
      autocomplete="off"
      #f2="ngForm"
      (SubmitRegion)="save($event)"
      [SaveRegion]="f2">
...
</form>
```

**Directive with one stream:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[SaveShop], [SaveRegion]'
})
export class SaveMerchantDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() SaveShop: any;
    @Input() SaveRegion: any;
    @Output() SubmitShop: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() SubmitRegion: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() debounce = 350;

    constructor(
        private saveService: SaveService,
        private $transitions: TransitionService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(this.debounce),
        switchMap((data: Object) => {
            if (!sessionStorage.getItem('dataRegion') || sessionStorage.getItem('dataRegion') === '{}') {
                sessionStorage.setItem('dataRegion', JSON.stringify(data));
            }

            this.$transitions.onBefore({}, () => {
                if (this.saveRegion.valid && !this.saveRegion.pristine) {
                    if (confirm(this.translate.instant(
                        'You are about to discard your REGION changes. Click "OK" to discard and navigate away! Click "Cancel" to stay.'
                    ))) {
                        this.discard();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (this.saveRegion.valid && !this.saveRegion.pristine) {
                window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: true }));

                return this.saveService.currentStatus$.pipe(
                    map(status => {
                        if (status === 'save') {
                            this.save(data);
                        } else if (status === 'discard') {
                            this.discard();
                        }
                    })
                );
            } else {
                return NEVER;
            }
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
this.$transitions.onExit({}, () => {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('dataRegion');
    status = 'false';
    this.saveService.changeStatus('false');
});
```

**How do I handle this?**

Can I simply do:

```
combineLatest(this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges, this.saveShop.form.valueChanges)
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(this.debounce),
        switchMap((data: Array<Object>) => {...
```

**Edit:**

Doing

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.saveShop.form.valueChanges,
    this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges
)
    .subscribe(...
```

gives `Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.`

Doing

```
combineLatest(
    this.saveShop.form.valueChanges,
    this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges
)
    .subscribe(...
```

gives me several problems where one is that 'form' cannot read undefined (since the two streams do not come in simultaneously one is undefined).
And if I add `startWith(null)` I get
`this.saveShop.form.valueChanges.startWith is not a function`

Comment: Can you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48882322/2148050) ?

Comment: Unfortunately not that simple...

Comment: @Zonaib please see updated tries --^

Comment: Can you build a bare minimum sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)?

Comment: To be honest I have never used stackblitz and my code base is humongous so not sure it is immediately doable. Sorry.

I am getting the form.valueChanges via @Input from two different components which seems to be the challenge with combineLatest...

Answer (score 0):

> And if I add startWith(null) I get this.saveShop.form.valueChanges.startWith is not a function

That at least is easily solved: this use of operators is deprecated (*possibly* would still work, if you imported the "right" `startWith` from the right file), instead use `.pipe` (as you are doing with other operators: `debounceTime`, `switchMap`), so

```
this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)) //...
```

(Alternatively, `concat(of(null), this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges)` would do).

Another thing: you can `filter` out any undefined/null values and just use "the good stuff", like this

```
combineLatest(
    this.saveShop.form.valueChanges.pipe(filter(value => Boolean(value)),
    this.saveRegion.form.valueChanges.pipe(filter(value => Boolean(value)),
//...
```

Comment: Thx will try this. Would it be possible to drop this and instead 'wait for' both streams to be notNull before executing?

Comment: Thx it's the `this.saveShop` `this.saveRegion` that are undefined though so I never get further than `form` -> `Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`.

So I thought it would somehow be possible to wait until both of these are not undefined (I need the data - a null value is useless in the present switchMap)

Comment: Oh. Then it'll be best if you create another question out of it, it has little to do with streams and much more with where `saveShop` and `saveRegion` come from.

Comment: You might be right but since ngOnInit apparently fires once per @Input (even though they are arriving simultaneously). Therefore I first get `[this.saveShop === somethingGood, this.saveRegion === undefined]` and next I get `[this.saveShop === undefined, this.saveRegion === somethingGood]`... So I believe it is indeed about streams as I need both streams in the same pipe!? If it is not doable I will try to split my ngOnInit function into several functions.

Comment: `ngOnInit` fires once in lifetime of a component (is it destroyed/recreated, by some `*ngIf` for example?). Difficult to say what's happening without seeing some more relevant code, though.